# Mejor Método para pintar el texto de un botón al dar Clic sobre él, pero si presiono otro este vuelva a su color original y el otro se pinte C#

Tags: c#

¡Cordial saludo a todos!

Tengo el siguiente método para cambiar el color el texto de los botones en la vista principal de mi proyecto, pero es un código superlargo, es decir si fueran 1.000 botones se haría un código aún más inmenso... ¿quién sabe cómo reducir ese código o conoce otra codificación para lograr este mismo FIN?, (es decir mi método funciona a la perfección lo malo es la cantidad de código).

Este método lo llamo en el evento MauseLeave de cada boton.

la aplicación es en C# 2019 WindwsForm.

```
    prívate  void PintarTextoButton()
    {
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmAlmacen))
            {
                btnacercade.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnalmacen.ForeColor = Color.White;

                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmGastosBancarios))
            {
                btnalmacen.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnGastobancos.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmSeriesCajas))
            {
                btnGastobancos.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnseriecajas.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmFormasdepago))
            {
                btnseriecajas.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnformaspago.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmPersonas))
            {
                btnformaspago.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnpersonas.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmCategoria))
            {
                btnpersonas.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btncategorias.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmGastoMenor))
            {
                btncategorias.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnGastomenor.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmRegistroDiario))
            {
                btnGastomenor.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnRegistrodiario.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmMisInformes))
            {
                btnRegistrodiario.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnestadistica.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmUsuarios))
            {
                btnestadistica.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnusuarios.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmConnec))
            {
                btnusuarios.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnconexion.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(FrmRolesUser))
            {
                btnconexion.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnroles.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(Manual))
            {
                btnroles.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnmanual.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else if (frm.GetType() == typeof(Acercade))
            {
                btnmanual.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnacercade.ForeColor = Color.White;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                btnalmacen.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnGastobancos.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnseriecajas.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnformaspago.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnpersonas.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btncategorias.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnGastomenor.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnRegistrodiario.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnestadistica.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnusuarios.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnconexion.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnroles.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnmanual.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
                btnacercade.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
            }
        }



    //Hacemmos Hover y Leave



    private void btnalmacen_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnalmacen.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }

    private void btnalmacen_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //llamamos el metodo
        PintarTextoButton();
    }
```

Comment: si es buton, entonces es una clase standar de tipo boton.. no importa el nombre del boton, importa que es un objeto boton ;)... tu codigo, deberian ser 4 lineas a lo sumo... tenes una variable con el boton que esta pintado (de tipo button) y recibis el nuevo boton a pintar, despintas el viejo, pintas el nuevo, apuntas al nuevo...

Comment: Hola, la Comunidad agradeceria que si alguna de las respuestas dadas en tu pregunta es correcta o te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, marques estas como respondida, adicional esto te dara resputacion como usuario y en tu cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

El primer argumento de los eventos en winforms es `object sender` el cual es el objeto que gatilló dicho evento, donde solo necesitas "castearlo" para poder manupularlo.

Ejemplo:

```
private void btn_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
}

private void btn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
}
```

No está de sobra aclarar que **NO** debes crear este par de evento por cada botón, si no que tu tienes un solo evento *Leave* que es común a todos los botones e igualmente con el *Hover*

---

Ahora bien, esto funciona cuando todos los botones son iguales pero si tu tienes un botón cuyo `ForeColor` es otro color distinto no funcionará. Por ejemplo tienes un botón que su ForeColor es rojo, al hacer hover se convierte en blanco y luego con el leave a `LightGray` en vez de retornar a lo original que era rojo.

Para solucionar esto debes guardar en unas variables tanto el color original como el botón que ha sido modificado, para que con estos datos poder restaurarlos a su estado original. Puedes apoyarte en una clase, por ejemplo:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ColorHover colorHover;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        colorHover = new ColorHover();
    }

    private void btn_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        colorHover.GuardarColor(btn);
        btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }

    private void btn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorHover.RestaurarColor();
    }
}
public class ColorHover
{
    public Button boton { get; set; } = null;
    public Color foreColor { get; set; }

    public void GuardarColor(Button btn)
    {
        foreColor = btn.ForeColor;
        boton = btn;
    }

    public void RestaurarColor()
    {
        if (boton != null)
        {
            boton.ForeColor = foreColor;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: La respuesta es muy buena.. peroooooo.. no es sobre hover y leave, es sobre click, lo que la hace mucho mas simple (un solo metodo).... la clase parece una sobredimension del problema (son solo dos variables)...

Comment: Bueno todo me parece correcto, pero hay una variante y es que yo valido si X Formulario está abierto, si está abierto entonces fíjeme el color que quiero, de lo contrario déjelo en su color original, ese sería la complicación.